# Determine lat/lon intersection on earth from point in space along 3d line

Tags: vector, intersection, wgs84, latitude-longitude, altitude

I have a known point in space with a lat,lon,alt.
It has a camera with a line of sight and a angle of field of view. I can take the central point and calculate each corner vector of the field of view, but..

How do I calculate the intersection with the earth (not necessarily at MSL) from these 3D lines from a point in space? I already know the *height* of this intersection, but need the lat/lon.

If the earth was flat and square - then that is simple trigonometry.
But curvature of the earth and rounded longitude lines has me stumped; and I can't find anything on the net that seems to provide a first step..
I will implement the solution in c#.

Any advice from the 3D gurus here?!

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81556/how-to-convert-geodetic-pose-cartesian-offset-to-geodetic-position?lq=1 and especially http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30448/local-coordinate-to-geocentric

Comment: Strangely, the same question was asked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86031/intersection-between-a-ray-from-lat-lon-alt-with-pan-tilt-and-earths-surfac?rq=1  but no actual answer given there.

Comment: How do you know the height of the intersection? What sort of terrain model do you have?